# How to use Header Footer in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Reactjs(Nextjs), I want to create file "header" and "footer" so i can use this file in all pages,So i want to know how can i do this and which is better option

1. Should i create "Layout.js" and then call Header in this file
2. Or should i use "Header"  and "footer" in _app.js (without create layout file)

Here is my layout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';

class Layout extends Component {
  

    render () {
        const { children } = this.props
        return (
          <div className='layout'>
            <Header />
            {children}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

or there is any other way,How can i do this,Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts) documentation for basic layout feature in NextJs

First create Layout component

```
import Header from './header'
import Footer from './footer'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

Import and use the <**Layout**> component in the entry file,

```
// pages/_app.js

import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      {/* All your page components */}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

This will wrap your page components in the Header and Footer included in the Layout.

Comment: entry file means "_app.js" file ?

Comment: @Rick Yes, as per the documentation.

Comment: lets suppose we have different headers ( 2 ) for different page then what should i do then ? ( just asking for knowledge)

Comment: @Rick it is explained here  - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts

Comment: What's the point of creating this abstraction instead of just putting the layout components directly into `_app.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

First create your Header & Footer then if you are using React.js go to App and put header and footer there like below:

```js
const App = () => {
 return (
  <>
   <Header />
     // your routes go here 
   <Footer />
  </>
 )
}
```

For Next.js go to _app.tsx/jsx the entry point of all your pages

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
   <>
    <Header />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
    <Footer />
   </>
  );
}
```

if you want to make different layouts or isolate that layout in a separate component you can do so.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir,I am working with Nextjs, But please explain this line "if you want to make different layouts or.." , dont understand the meaning of "different layouts"

Comment: Header and footer should be in "pages" or "components" folder ?

Comment: I meant by different layouts that some pages have different header and footer than the others then you should make a component for each layout and wrap the routes that consumes it with it.

Comment: each file in the pages folder is a route in the app so putting the header there will make it a route `/header` so you should puth the header in a components directory.

Comment: why not you are using "layout.js" file , kindly explain ?

Comment: @Ismail_Aj it seems you miss understand the question